# Best way to call suspend coroutine from Executor(ThreadPoolExecutor)

Tags: android, android-camera, kotlin-coroutines

I am currently developing face detection with with a camera library & mlkit.

Camera library provides a `FrameProcessor` in which I am getting `Frame` in a stream manner. I have written `FrameProcessingTask` inside a suspend function.

Inside cameralib `FrameProcessor` is called inside a `ThreadPoolExecutor`

```
mFrameProcessingExecutor.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {
                    for (FrameProcessor processor : mFrameProcessors) {
                        try {
                            processor.process(frame);
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            LOG.w("Frame processor crashed:", e);
                        }
                    }
                    frame.release();
                }
            });
```

In my side I have written :

```
private val processor = FrameProcessor { frame ->
runBlocking { // used runBlocking to bridge suspend coroutine
    frameProcessingTask(frame)
    }
}

suspend fun frameProcessingTask(frame: Frame) = withContext(Dispatchers.Default)
 //face detection & processing code written here.
}
```

My question :

1. is it right to use `runBlocking` inside `Executor` as it's called continuously in each frame.
2. what happened to suspend `runBlocking` part if `Executor` canceled the task
3. what happened if `processor.process(frame);` called again before `frameProcessingTask` finished it's task.

Comment: Why do you need to use a coroutine here? `processor.process(frame)` is already called in its own `Executor`.

Comment: ml kit detection used callbacks which I needed to convert it suspend function & use it. @Sergey

Answer (score 0):

> 1. is it right to use runBlocking inside Executor as it's called continuously in each frame.

If your code is being called as part of a blocking interface that expects the work to be done when the method returns, you don't have a choice but to block the thread until the work is done. The point of `runBlocking` is to enable calling suspend functions from this kind of places. `FrameProcessor` qualifies here.

> 2. what happened to suspend runBlocking part if Executor canceled the task

If the task hasn't started yet, cancelling simply removes the task from the queue.

If the task has already completed, cancelling has no effect.

If the task is running, then the thread may be *interrupted* in an attempt to cancel the task (this depends on the [mayInterruptIfRunning](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Future.html#cancel-boolean-) param used when cancelling the task).

In that last case, assuming the thread is already executing `runBlocking`, you can refer to the `runBlocking` [documentation](https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-blocking.html):

*If this blocked thread is interrupted (see Thread.interrupt), then the coroutine job is cancelled and this runBlocking invocation throws InterruptedException.*

So the answer is that your coroutine will be cancelled (which is probably what you expect).

> 3. what happened if processor.process(frame); called again before frameProcessingTask finished it's task

It depends on `mFrameProcessingExecutor`. If it's multithreaded, then another task can be run in parallel of the previous one.

Comment: Probably also worth to mention runInterruptible - https://kotlin.github.io/kotlinx.coroutines/kotlinx-coroutines-core/kotlinx.coroutines/run-interruptible.html it also will try to interrupt blocking code if it supports it

Comment: @gildor `runInterruptible` is for the opposite use case: running blocking (but interruptible) code from coroutines, so I don't believe it is relevant to mention it in this answer

Comment: Ahh, you are absolutely right, I so used to suspend functions